# Non-Int-based death attack (aside from marrulurk and Marchosias)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, assassin

I know of two sources of death attack that use Charisma, rather than Intelligence, for the save DC: the marrulurk race from *Sandstorm*, and the 7th-level vestige Marchosias, King of Killers from *Tome of Magic*. As far as I know, there are no options for a Wisdom-based death attack.

Are there any others, or ways to convert an Int-based death attack to use Charisma or Wisdom? (Or Strength, Dexterity, or Constitution, I guess, though I’d be very surprised).

Charisma is preferred, as is something accessible in a single level, as death attack is from assassin 1st (among others), but ultimately I’d like the complete list—because I’m pretty sure it’s empty.

A lot of lists note the *death touch* ability of the Death domain, slayer of Domiel, etc. That’s not of interest to me: anything with a daily restriction is not what I’m looking for. Studying the target is an acceptable cost, obviously. Things that “effectively” kill the target, like paralysis or petrification, are acceptable, even if they are not named “death attack.”

Any 3.5e-legal Wizards of the Coast material, or *Dragon* or *Dungeon* material, is acceptable. I am ideally seeking a complete list, which again might very well be an empty list.

Comment: Does being a non-int based caster count? So, casting a death spell as a Cleric?

Comment: @goodguy5 “anything with a daily restriction is not what I’m looking for” And anyway, no, I’m ideally looking for an Ex ability, though I’d consider a Su one.

Comment: ah yea, fair. For some reason, spells didn't occur to me as a daily restriction.

Comment: What if you put an ability into a wand with unlimited uses?

Comment: @goodguy5 No, not what I’m looking for.

Comment: what if it has no save, like the blackweave warlock?

Comment: I thought Blackweave Warlock was in Dungeon Magazine #100, but I can't find it. If it is there, then that

Comment: @goodguy5 Blackweave warlock was in _Polyhedron_ vol. 159, which was an insert in _Dungeon_ vol. 100, I believe. Anyway, it just has death touch à la the Death domain or slayer of Domiel.

Comment: ah ha! Searching polyhedron was the ticket. It's Death Touch, but with 2d6 instead of 1d6. good find. I'll add it, I guess

Comment: @goodguy5 I’d really rather you didn’t, seeing as the majority of your answer is things _I specifically asked **not** be included_. You have a good answer with deathstalker of Bhaal, but adding so much extraneous stuff really just takes away from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could only find two that didn't have uses-per-day limits.

#### Deathstalker of Bhaal

(DrMag 322)
Standard Death Attack, but:

> If the victim of such an attack fails her Fortitude saving throw (DC 10 + double the deathstalker's level + the deathstalker's Charisma modifier) against the kill effect, she dies.

#### Darkwood Stalker (gotta mention it)

(complete warrior, 23)

> Death Attack (Ex): If a 10th-level darkwood stalker studies a particular orc for 3 rounds and then makes a sneak attack with a melee weapon that successfully deals damage, the sneak attack has the additional effect of possibly killing the target. While studying the orc, the darkwood hunter can undertake other actions as long as his attention stays focused on the target and the target does not detect the darkwood stalker or recognize the darkwood stalker as an enemy. If the victim of such an attack fails a Fortitude save (DC 10 + the darkwood stalker’s class level + the darkwood stalker’s Wis modifier), he dies. If the victim’s saving throw succeeds, the attack is just a normal sneak attack. Once the darkwood stalker has completed the 3 rounds of study, he must make the death attack within the next 3 rounds. If a death attack is attempted and fails (the victim makes his save) or if the darkwood stalker does not launch the attack within 3 rounds of completing the study, 3 new rounds of study are required before he can attempt another death attack.

---

I know that these were excluded, but a few examples that I found WITH uses per day were

**Nightmare Spinner**
3/day (Complete Mage p74)

**Warrior of the Animal Fist (Shen) - Tiger**
1/day/level (DrMag 319)

**OsteoMancer**
1+/day (DrMag 315)

**Infused** (Exalted prestige class)
3/day (DrMag 321)

**Blackweave Warlock**
1-3/day (Polyhedron #159 p15)

Comment: Deadly Nightmare is 3x per day. Osteomncer, Infused, Warrior of...,  all have daily limits too. Still +1 for the DeathStalker. Looked it up, and it req's 3rd level Divine Casting.

Comment: @Chemus dang it!

Comment: Yeah, but the requirements comment was not a detraction, simply trying to add info.

Comment: Yeah, I’d prefer to avoid non-answering things here; deathstalker of Bhaal (the ‘s’ isn’t capitalized, by the way) is a fine answer all by itself, and of course darkwood stalker is valid too, though it’s been covered. But kudos on the deathstalker; that’s a great find that might work very well for my purposes, depending on how well I can cheese the 3rd-level divine spell requirement.

Comment: @KRyan yea I forgot/didn't notice the limits

Answer (score 6):

### There Can Be Only **One**!

**10th level** Darkwood Stalker (*Complete Warrior*, 23) is Wis based, but seems to be vs orcs only, and requires 10 levels of Darkwood Stalker, so probably doesn't fit...

Comment: I actually checked this one, and yet somehow missed it. Probably stopped reading after I saw it could only target orcs, since that’s patently useless, but still, +1 as it fits the criteria in the question.

Comment: @KRyan I don't have a machine searchable Dragon resource, so that's probably the best I can get you for a 3.5e list. For me, it's like trying to find a needle in a needlestack.

Comment: As far as I know, there _isn’t one_, so yeah, this is just kinda hoping that someone out there happens to have played such a thing or something and remembers it. Of course, again, I’d be kinda surprised if there actually is anything out there, but then, darkwood stalker was, so maybe.

Comment: https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?178309-Death-Attack-Classes-3-5 seems like a pertinent resource.

Comment: @BenBarden Wanna make that into an answer? Looks like a very good one!

Comment: I won't add this to the answer, due to the ***cheese*** (I mean limburger, here) factor, and the *potential* tenuousness of the qualification, but a 1st level changeling with 13+ Wis taking Assume Supernatural Ability: Petrifying Gaze, and then assuming the form of a Medusa can petrify most anything...

Comment: @KRyan I'm not up for the effort to filter the cheese and transcribe.  If anyone else wants to, by all means feel free.

Comment: @Chemus A changeling’s *minor change shape* is purely superficial and would not work with Assume Supernatural Ability; you’d need *alter self* or better, which makes it daily-limited again. I guess there’s thrall of Juiblex, for at-will *polymorph*, but that is very definitely not what I was asking for.

Comment: @BenBarden Fair enough; deathstalker of Bhaal does seem to be the best fit for this question anyway, and that’s been handled.

Comment: @KRyan *Races of Eberron*'s wording of the Racial Emulation feat: *When you use your minor change shape ability to **assume the form of a humanoid creature***, shows that Keith Baker, et. al. assume otherwise, whether intentionally or not. Your reaction is why it's *potentially* tenuous qualification, and the fact that *if it works* it's available from first level is why its cheese. And why I relegated it to a comment.